# Escaping forward slashes : Windows CMD and Bash

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, escaping

I have a situation where I need to invoke a UNIX Shell from a windows CMD file. This is invoked as below:

sh -c **path**/script.sh

The challenge I am having is path is passed as a parameter to the windows cmd and contains the backward slash () to delimit the path. So a command execution like so:

sh -c e:\scriptpath\test.sh fails as sh correctly reports: e:scriptpathtest.sh does not exist.

Escaping the \ with a \ works: e.g. **sh -c e:\\scriptpath\\test.sh** will work.

The question is: how do I include the \ in the entered path parameter from within the windows cmd file? e.g. if path is entered as e:\scriptpath, it will automatically get converted to e:\\scriptpath?

Comment: Please provide an example of the way how a _path is passed as a parameter to the windows cmd_. A registry entry? Drag&drop into an opened `cmd` window? A `start "" cmd /C command path`? Another?

Comment: I prompt for the path in windows and pass the entered value to sh. e.g. set /p path=Enter script path: and call it as below: sh -c %path%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Never** change the `%path%` environment variable in the way described (`set /p path=Enter path`). Use another name instead (e.g. `set /p _path=Enter path`). The [`%path%` variable has a special meaning in Windows environment](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) and its proper value has *vital importance* here. See also [`PATH` command](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html).

Any user input should be thoroughly checked before using, e.g.

- check whether [(fully or partially qualified) file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths) exists and
- translate to Unix filename conventions, see [`%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%` etc.: Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Save below code snippet with `.bat` or `.cmd` file extension, e.g. `32134824.cmd`:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
:UserInput
rem empty the `_path` variable
set "_path="
rem or set a default value for it as follows:
set "_path=e:\scriptpath\test.sh"
rem prompt for user input
set /p "_path=Enter path [default=%_path%]:"
rem treat the case `set "_path="` and the user pressed only ˙Enter˙
if not defined _path echo wrong path & goto :UserInput
rem or set a default value instead: if not defined _path set "_path=%CD%\test.sh"

rem check if the file exists:
if not exist "%_path%" echo %_path%: file does not exist & goto :UserInput

rem translate to Unix filename conventions
set "_path=%_path:\=/%"
rem or set "_path=%_path:\=\\%"

rem next `sh` command is merely echoed for debugging purposes
echo sh -c %_path%
```

**Further resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (special reference) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)

Comment: path was a typo. I meant to type in _path, as you have done. anyways your solution helped me with the issue. Thanks. I have accepted the solution also.

Answer (score 0):

Windows also supports a forward slash between directories.
Try `sh -c e:/scriptpath/test.sh`

Comment: I could do that. However, since the path is being prompted for, e.g. set /p path=Enter path: and then being passed as sh -c %path%, I cannot expect that users will indeed enter forward slashes. Sigh !

Comment: Can you replace the backslashes with forward slashes? Try in cmd `set p=e:a\b\c` (initial setting), change with `set p=%p:\=/%` and check with
`echo "%p%"`